# How do I open a new HTML page with eel (python library)?

Tags: python, html, css, eel

I've just started learning all programming thing and came across this python library "eel" where you can create a decent GUI out of HTML. However, there are not many tutorials available or decent example projects available out there to study from. Here's what I want to do but I don't know how to achieve it. If you guys can help me out, it'd be greatly appreciated.

1. I have (currently 2) HTML pages one used as a landing page for login (index.html) and one use as a man application (main.html).
2. A main.py where I import and connect eel.
3. A login.py where I create a list of login credentials: username and password

Basically, when I open the main.py, the index.html will open up, and enter the correct login credential (let's say username: user1 | password: 12345) and hit the button, the main application (main.html) will appear, otherwise it shows "incorrect username or password".

So, the code looks like this in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        eel.expose(open_vwmain);
        function open_vwmain_js(x){
            $(window.location = ".../web/main.html")
        }

        <!-- upon button click, html eel sends out the user and pw entered in this index.html to python -->
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            eel.login($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in my main.py it looks like this:

```
 eel.init('web')
@eel.expose                      
def login(username, password):
    # logic -> Check for right user/ login suceeded
    if username == check_data.USER and password == check_data.PW:
        eel.open_vwmain_js(open_vwmain)
    else:
        eel.open_vwmain_js(error)

eel.start('index.html',size=(800,600), port=8080)
```

Note, I have not added the popup error message yet because it isn't that important for now. I just have no idea how to make this first step to work yet.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

just make eel.start with a new port
you can close the other window then

Answer (score 0):

Why not

1. loading the index.html with hidden "logged_in" class sections (divs, tabs,...),
2. populating and unhiding them if login successful and hiding the "login" class section,
3. upon logout hiding the "logged_in" class sections, clearing their inner html and unhiding the "login" class sections again?